# Is there a C function which, given a struct array with different data types, can sort the array with any one of the data types

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, struct

I am sorting/searching a struct array.

```
struct Substance
{
   char name[NAME_SIZE]
   int mass;
   double halftime;
}
```

The sorting/searching is done after prompting the user to choose what member of the struct to sort by, i.e by name, mass or halftime.

Is there a way to make a general function that can work with all of the three data types or do I have to write different functions for each?

The reason why I don't want to write several functions is that 90% of the code in each function would be the same.

I am especially struggling with the fact that I have to get the member I want to operate on for each iteration, i.e `substances[i].mass` to access the mass and this syntax obviously has to be different for each member of the struct.

I tried to do some pre processing to avoid this issue:

```
switch(choice)
{
   case '1':
      memcpy(current, substances[i].name, NAME_SIZE);
      break;
   case '2':
      sprintf(current, "%d", substances[i].mass);
      break;
   case '3':
      sprintf(current, "%lf", substances[i].halftime);
}
```

But if I want to sort by `mass` I would then have to convert every other substance's `mass` in the struct array aswell.

I have also thought about representing every member as the same data type in the first place and then just convert in when needed, like printing, writing to file etc but I don't know what data type I would use.

A general use case would be:

```
/*
Do you want to sort by (1) name, (2) mass or (3) halftime: 2

Sorted list by mass:
Name      Mass     Halftime
Zirconium 91       ...
Radon     220      ...
Radon     222      ...
Uranium   238      ...
*/
```

Comment: You can just use [`qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) (or your own sort function) with three different `compar` functions.

Comment: @Silop You can use qsort and for each data member of the structure you will need to write a separate comparison function.

Comment: Glibc provides the function [`qsort_r()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort_r) which takes an extra pointer argument which is passed to the comparison function, so you could write one comparison function that decides which data member to sort based on the extra argument. But, that's not portable C anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes [qsort()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm).  example:

Given struct:

```
struct Substance
{
   char name[NAME_SIZE]
   int mass;
   double halftime;
};
```

And assuming array defined `substances[N];//has been populated`, then examples of calls can be:

```
qsort(substances, N, sizeof (struct Substance), compareName);
qsort(substances, N, sizeof (struct Substance), compareMass);
qsort(substances, N, sizeof (struct Substance), compareHtime);
```

...with the forms for your compare functions being passed in `qsort()` being:

```
int compareName(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct Substance *ia = a;
    const struct Substance *ib = b;
    return strcmp(ia->name, ib->name);//returns -1, 0 1 per strcmp rules
}

int compareMass(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct Substance *ia = a;
    const struct Substance *ib = b;
    return ia->mass == ib->mass ? 0 : 
                                  ia->mass > ib->mass ? 1 : -1;
}

int compareHtime(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct Substance *ia = a;
    const struct Substance *ib = b;
    return fabs(ia->halftime - ib->halftime) < 0.00001 ? 0 :
                                (ia->halftime - ib->halftime) > 1 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

> *"Is there a way to make a general function that can work with all of the three data types or do I have to write different functions for
> each?"*

You could create a void function that uses your `switch()`, and uses an `enum`.  to decide which of the three compare functions to call.   Eg:

```
enum {
    NAME,
    MASS,
    HALF,
    TYPE_MAX
};

void sort(struct Substance *s, size_t size, int type)
{
    switch(type)
        case NAME;
            qsort(s, size, sizeof (struct Substance), compareName);
            break;
        case 
              ...
```

Comment: There are typos in the `return` statements of the last two functions. `(ia->mass ib->mass )` missing operator.

Comment: They're also returning one of the two raw values, not negative/0/positive (typically `-1/0/1`) based on ordering.

Comment: @kaylum - have edited last two functions.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The casts aren't necessary.

Comment: @bush - are you referring to, eg: `(const struct Substance *)a;`  ??

Comment: @ryyker Thank you so much for the detailed answer! Just out of curiousty, why is it that you use the `const`  prefix in the compare functions?

Comment: @Silop -  To ensure that the arguments cannot be changed.

Comment: There is no need to cast when converting `a` to `ia`

Comment: @dbush - Thanks.  Edited out all unnecessary casts.